# Is there a way for a mere mortal to delete tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking through some of the questions today and it looks like some of the newly created tags are completely unnecessary, the [lowpass-filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lowpass-filter) tag [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-can-i-lowpass-filter-by-only-reducing-peak-data), [sinusoidal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sinusoidal) tag [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/101/best-way-to-extend-a-1-d-signal-for-a-longer-period-of-time), [highpass-filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/highpass-filter) tag [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/71/what-is-the-physical-interpretation-of-lowpass-highpass-filtering) and so on. Not all of them should be tags. There are more, and it's starting to look like we need to clean up. How do we do it and who has the privileges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is, using [Tag Synonyms](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms). To quote the page:

> Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or
>   more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer
>   score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more, can vote for
>   tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they
>   reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score
>   of -2.

Alternatively, if there is a tag that is only used in 1-2 questions, simply retag it to something more appropriate, and the original will be deleted, eventually..

Lastly, if we bring a specific list of tags that need to be combined, and can all agree, a moderator could do it for us.

Comment: Didn't see all the options there, thanks.

Comment: BTW: try not to synonymize tags that don't mean the same thing. Should be obvious from the name, but...

Comment: On the point of your original tag getting deleted. Specifically, **when there are 0 live instances of a tag, it will be deleted at the end of the day**.